# Get resultat data from an array

Tags: sql, arrays, laravel

I'm using Laravel and I've used this query to fetch records:

```
<?php
foreach ($connectionUser as $value) {
    if ($value->sender_profile_id == $profile_id) {
        //$profileID[] = $value->receiver_profile_id;
        $result[] .= $this->select('assets.id', 'assets.profile_id', 'assets.access', 'assets.name', 'assets_data.path', 'assets.processed'
                           ->join('assets_data', 'assets.id', '=', 'assets_data.asset_id')
                           ->where('profile_id', '=', $value->receiver_profile_id)->orderBy('assets.created_at', 'desc')
                           ->get();
    } elseif ($value->receiver_profile_id == $profile_id) {
        //$profileID[] = $value->sender_profile_id;
        $result[] .= $this->select('assets.id', 'assets.profile_id', 'assets.access', 'assets.name', 'assets_data.path', 'assets.processed')
                          ->join('assets_data', 'assets.id', '=', 'assets_data.asset_id')
                          ->where('profile_id', '=', $value->sender_profile_id)
                          ->orderBy('assets.created_at', 'desc')
                          ->get();
    }
}
```

And the result look like this (`print_r($result)`)

```
Array (
    [0] => []
    [1] => [{"id":233,"profile_id":175,"access":"PUB","name":"99","path":"Capture_233.PNG","processed":"0"}]
    [2] => [] 
)
```

How can I get the result datas?

Comment: Just a random thought! Shouldn't `$result[] .=` be `$result[] =` as you are pushing in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you post, I guess you are trying to retrieve id, profile_id, access from assets table. For question,

> any alternative way in laravel to execute above query?

It's better use to eloquent ORM instead of using raw queries. All what you have to do is define the the relationships in the model classes and use the related models as properties.

Check the Laravel Document

[Getting Started with Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)

[Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the array result from the query, and check if there is a result, then you push it to `$result`.

To get the data after finishing that code, you can loop to the `$result` values (which it will be another array, if you want one result from the query you can take the first on `->first()`).